# Firebase Cloud Function get logs of the same trigger job

Tags: logging, google-cloud-functions

I want to view log on https://console.cloud.google.com/logs but there are too much logs from a lot of triggers. Sometime I want to view all logs of a single trigger to know what happened on this single run.

The idea is use a `uuid` like below, but if using it, I have to pass this `uuid` as a param to all child functions -> looks bad.

```
logger.setTriggerId(UUID().toString())
```

###### Sample code

`child.ts`

```
function childFunction() {
    logger.info("child function log") // (3)
}
```

`index.ts`

```
import { logger } from 'firebase-functions/v2';

export const onSomethingTrigged = onDocumentWritten(`CollectionName/{docId}`, (event) => {
  logger.setTriggerId(UUID().toString()) // Something like this?

  childFunction()

  logger.info(`onSomethingTrigged: some log info`, randomId()) // (1)
  logger.info(`onSomethingTrigged: some another log info`, randomId()) // (2)
}
```

As above sample code, I want to return only `3` rows of `(1)`, `(2)` and `(3)`

###### Query logs

```
...
textPayload =~ "<uuid string>"
```

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you checked this [git link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/560), does it help you to resolve your issue?

Comment: I tried to query by execution_id but it’s not return logs from single trigger.